# Почему файлы шейдеров в Android Studio отображаются по-разному?

Tags: android, opengl

[image: так выглядят файлы типа glsl]

Тема для меня новая, поэтому допускаю, что могу спросить какую-то глупость. Тем не менее, при создании вершинного и фрагментного шейдера наблюдается такая картина, а само приложение выводит белый экран (хотя отрабатываю вроде как рабочий пример со стартандроид). Допускаю, что причина именно в этом, похоже среда не хавает файл фрагментного шейдера.

Перепроверил уже все раза по три, или так все и должно выглядеть?

Comment: Idea (оно же AndroidStudio) подставляет иконку в соответствии с содержимым файла

Comment: Скорее всего у вас в `fragment_shader` проблемы с синтаксисом. Соответственно потому не отображает и иконку правильную не ставит

Comment: все перепроверил еще раз в соответствии с исходником: https://github.com/startandroid/lessons_opengl/tree/master/lesson169_shaders/src/main/res/raw Когда удаляю файлы и создаю заново в Raw, то вновь созданный vertex_shader.glsl уже подсвечивается как надо, а все остальное не распознает...

Comment: disclaimer - я с openGL шейдерами дел не имел. Но, по опыту - попробуйте "Build"->"Clean project" , потом "File"->"Invalidate caches / Restart"

Comment: Надо Сплинтера спросить.

Comment: Подскажите, удалось найти решение? У меня такая же проблема, не корректно работает если использовать имя fragment_shader.glsl с другими именами иконка отображается корректно, но треугольник не появляется.